# Understanding how javascript code is download in a google home device, for local home execution (action on google smart home)

Tags: javascript, local, execution, google-home

I try to understand how my javascript code that handle local execution bahavior is download in my google home mini. I know I give an url towards a server or a web page here :

[Action google interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoVI6.png)

And this code is used in my google home to handle local execution but I just put my web page url here, in the **test tab**. So if I want to deploy my app in a **production environnement**, how will i do that ? I did not see any other place to put the url toward my code.

I red this page: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local

And followed this tuto: https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-local

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found my response. For now, local execution is just in preview. So no production management is implemented yet.